# add/remove Class with click anywhere to remove class except child elements or child cancel button

Tags: jquery, html, function, toggle

I'm attempting to create a navigation that transitions on click event. It also contains a link with another transition effect on click event. I want to use a class so that I can style accordingly with the media queries. I'm new to JS/jQuery and I've researched/managed to get the toggles to work but I'm stuck in trying to cleanly write a method to achieve the following:

When click on on `nav-toggle`

- addClass isVisible to `.nav-toggle`
- addClass isVisible to `.menu`

When click on `eventList-toggle`

- remove class isVisible from `.nav-toggle`
- remove class isVisible from `.menu`
- add class isVisible to `#events`

When click anywhere other than `#events` or on submit and cancel buttons

- remove class isVisible from `#events`

I wrote a basic fiddle with what I currently have but still can't get the submit and cancel buttons to close the `#events` element nor does this hide the `menu` on click of Events stuff link (`menu` will only hide in device viewports hence the class). [https://jsfiddle.net/ngoh8gej](https://jsfiddle.net/ngoh8gej/):

I may be way off in my code and even embarrassed but I believe this gets the point across for the question. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ngoh8gej/17/

Comment: Sorry, but in your example, clicking either button or anywhere within the `.main` section doesn't close the `#events` div

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle with your requests:

https://jsfiddle.net/ngoh8gej/18/

I cleaned up some code (removed the unecessary `$(function(){`), added an ID to the submit and cancel buttons, added the event to handle them:

```
$('#submit, #cancel').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

and changed your event to close the `#events` div:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id !== 'events') {
    $('.isVisible').removeClass('isVisible')
  }
});
```

Comment: Still having issues with the code. :( I need the `nav-toggle` to apply the class of `.isVisible` to `.menu` and `.nav-toggle` and close when click anywhere in the document. I also need the `.eventList-toggle` to remove the `.isVisible` class from `.menu` and `.nav-toggle`, apply `.isVisible` to `#events` while click anywhere except within `#events` removes `.isVisible` from the `#events` div unless it's the `submit` or `#cancel` buttons.